# bash script get files in subfolders which contains a special line

Tags: bash

I need your help with a short bash script. I have a folder, which contains about 150,000(!) xml-files. I need a script which extracts all those files, which contain a specified line. The script should be work as fast as possible, because the script have to be used very often.

My first approach was the following, using grep:

```
for f in temp/*
do
   if grep "^.*the line which should be equal.*$" "$f" 
   then 
      echo "use this file"
   else 
      echo "this file does not contain the line"
   fi
done
```

This approach works, but it takes too much time. Does somebody know an faster approach? If another scripting language is a better choice, it is also ok.

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: Always avoid executing a 'command-per-file' if at all possible; that is inevitably slower than having one command process many files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grep without any bash handlers.

```
   -l, --files-with-matches
          Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first  match.   (-l  is
          specified by POSIX.)
```

So, try this:

```
grep "the line which should be equal" --files-with-matches  temp/*
```

Comment: 150k files may be too much for arguments, if you hit the "Argument list too long" error read this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/095